# Changing format of Date in sql Excel

Tags: sql, excel

I have data with date format like `DD.MM.YYYY` but I need `DD/MM/YYYY`.

I tried useing `clng(DATE)`, `int(DATE)` or `format(DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')` but it didn't work.

I am using Excel 2010 in Windows7 and ODBC server creating query via wizard

```
SELECT distinct `ZV162$`.`Sales Document`, `ZV162$`.`Schedule Line Number`
, `ZV162$`.`Document Date`, `ZV162$`.`Purchase order number`
, `ZV162$`.`Delivery block`, `ZV162$`.`Ship-to number`, `ZV162$`.`Ship-to name`
 , `ZV162$`.`Ship-to country`, `ZV162$`.`Unloading Point`, `ZV162$`.`Receiving point`
, `ZV162$`.`Incoterms (Part 1)`, `ZV162$`.`Loading Date`,  `ZV162$`.Plant
, `ZV162$`.`Delivery Number`, `ZV162$`.`Shipment Number`
, `ZV162$`.`Sea Shipment Number`, `ZV162$`.`Shipping Cond#`, `ZV162$`.`Trailer type`

FROM `ZV162$` `ZV162$`
```

Date is in Document Date and Loading Date

Comment: i want do it in query

Comment: Can you show us your query please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I read some stuffs do some testing and here is RIGHT solution

```
    IIF(`ZVSHPtemp$`.F5 is null, null, dateserial(Right(`ZVSHPtemp$`.F5,4),mid
(`ZVSHPtemp$`.F5,4,2),left(`ZVSHPtemp$`.F5,2))) as [Planned date of shipment start]
```

this is how it works! :)

so Answer to my question is DATESERIAL

Answer (score 0):

Excel tries hard to handle dates automatically.  If Document Date and Loading Date columns on the database are of Date or Timestamp type then you should expect Excel to format the column as a date if you populate using Range.CopyFromRecordSet or similar.  You can then use Excel cell formatting to chose whwther the separators are a period (.) or slash (/).

If the columns are of varchar type then you could try some SQL function such as to_date() or or its equivalent in your flavour of SQL.

In general you will have a better (more elegant/performant/maintainable) solution if you manipulate the columns in SQL rather than post-processing them with VBA functions.